# excel - averaging right to left cells - 12 valid months

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Need some advice regarding excel formulas.
How would you automatically average a range of cells from the right to left. (12 recent months ignoring exclusions.
What type formula would be viable?

See here https://i.stack.imgur.com/X76XC.jpg – the cells that should average out are in red.

Exclusions: 
jan 14 – as there is nothing there
dec 13 – as there is a negative sign (we ignore this)

Answer (score 1):

(Tested in Excel 2013)

Using the mocked-up image you provided with Dates in A1:U1 and Values in A2:U2...

Cell A4 and B4 - Set Data Validation to 'List' with a Source of **=$A$1:$U$1**.  This will insert drop-downs so you can select a Start Date (A4) and End Date (B4).

Cell A5 - **=AVERAGEIFS(A2:U2,A1:U1,">="&A4,A1:U1,"<="&B4,A2:U2,"<>",A2:U2,">=0")**

A5 will give you an Average of the values in A2:U2 with the following criteria:

- Greater than or equal to the selected date in A4
- Less than or equal to the selected date in B4
- Value is not blank
- Value is not negative

Comment: Works! but what is there any possible way to automatically set the start/end months based on the filled data? I have numerous rows of different active months and manually setting each one is definitely an effort.

Comment: So you're just looking for an average of the most recent twelve months that have positive values?

Comment: Well, if you can count on the months that haven't elapsed yet being blank, you can try this: **=AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(A2:U2,0,COUNT(A2:U2)-13),">=0")**